# Syntax error, unable to key email into SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

just like the title goes, I'm unable to key the email address into SQLite databases. The error is as followed:

```
02-01 09:49:52.300: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(16157): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "@gmail": syntax error, db=/data/data/com.proj.db/databases/FormDetails
```

There is nothing wrong in the creating of database it's only recently that I add into the email column then this error comes out. Is it because the "@" sign cannot be keyed into the database?

My code for the table:

```
String insertNewFormDetails = "create table if not exists " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                                                            + NAME + " text not null, "
                                                            + SCHOOL + " text not null, "
                                                            + CURRENTDATE + " text not null, "
                                                            + FORMTYPE + " text not null, "
                                                            + EMAIL + " text not null);";

    db.execSQL(insertNewFormDetails);
```

Comment: What is the value of `insertNewFormDetails` and each of the String variables you use to build it?

Comment: Note that your SQL statement is trying to create a table with some column names that come from other variables. This is *not* the same as inserting data, like the variable name suggests. Column names cannot contain the `@` character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not allowed to use the `@` in column name like `@Email` but you can still use it by using `square brackets` arround the column name like `[@email]`.

**Valid**:

`[@Email]`

**InValid**:

`@Email`

Please note that you need to reference this column like `[@Email]` in SQL queries and it will work.